# Sequelize - Update FOREIGN KEY constraint with ONDELETE CASCADE

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Postgres with Sequelize and I need to update an existing `ForeignKey` Constraint with `onDelete = Cascade`.

I have updated my model, but the migration file comes up as a skeleton. I haven't found a way to update this constraint.

**My model file**:

```
export const Property = sequelize.define<PropertyModel, PropertyAttribute>('property', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  status: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: true
  },
  publishedAt: Sequelize.DATE
});

Property.associate = models => {
  Property.belongsTo(models.User, {
    foreignKey: { allowNull: false },
    allowNull: false
  });
  Property.hasMany(
    models.PropertyService, {onDelete: "cascade"});

  Property.hasMany(
    models.Visitor, {onDelete: "cascade"});
};
```

**My migration file**:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      // How can I update a FK constraint??
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      // How can I undo an FK update constraint??
  }
};
```

Any ideas on how to make this migration?

Comment: Have you already written a migration for the `Property` model? Are you asking how to write a migration for `PropertyService` and `Visitor` models?

Comment: I already created the migration skeleton with sequelize migration: `migration:generate` it is empty. I just want to update the FK constraint to include a `on delete cascade`

Answer (score 15):

I found it simplest to first remove the existing constraint and then add it back with onDelete. Sequelize has `queryInterface.removeConstraint` and `queryInterface.addConstraint` methods for this.

Here is a contrived example:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const transaction = await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction();
    try {
      await queryInterface.removeConstraint(
        'users',
        'users_address_id_fkey',
        { transaction }
      );
      await queryInterface.addConstraint('users', ['address_id'], {
        type: 'foreign key',
        name: 'users_address_id_fkey',
        references: {
          table: 'addresses',
          field: 'id',
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        transaction
      });
      return transaction.commit();
    } catch (error) {
      await transaction.rollback();
      throw error;
    }
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const transaction = await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction();
    try {
      await queryInterface.removeConstraint(
        'users',
        'users_address_id_fkey',
        { transaction }
      );
      await queryInterface.addConstraint('users', ['address_id'], {
        type: 'foreign key',
        name: 'users_address_id_fkey',
        references: {
          table: 'addresses',
          field: 'id',
        },
        transaction
      });
      return transaction.commit();
    } catch (error) {
      await transaction.rollback();
      throw error;
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: `transaction` in your case does nothing, you need to include it to the queries

Comment: @ArnasPecelis - thank you, I've updated the answer to fix.

Comment: FYI @Stone and for the ones on sequelize v6, you need to place the fields inside of the option object e.g. `options.fields` otherwise it will throw an error [doc here](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-addConstraint)

Comment: @JoelBarenco - thanks for pointing this out. I've yet to upgrade to v6...

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is any way of manipulating constraints from within the standard Sequelize migrations queryInterface, so the way I've achieved this in the past is by running raw `ALTER TABLE` queries on PostgreSQL to drop and re-create the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, for example:

```
const tableName = 'property';
const constraintName = 'property_property_service_id_fkey';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(`alter table "${tableName}" drop constraint "${constraintName}"`)
      .then(() => queryInterface.sequelize.query(
        `alter table "${tableName}"
          add constraint "${constraintName}" foreign key("property_service_id") references "property_service" ("id")
          on delete cascade`
      ));
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(`alter table "${tableName}" drop constraint "${constraintName}"`)
      .then(() => queryInterface.sequelize.query(
        `alter table "${tableName}"\
          add constraint "${constraintName}" foreign key("property_service_id") references "property_service" ("id")
          on delete no action`
      ));
  },
};
```

Note that I've made some assumptions about your table, field and constraint names so you may need to adapt some of these depending on your Sequelize configuration settings.

Comment: Thanks! In fact I have something very similar to your suggestion but I keep getting ERROR: Unexpected Token ;

Comment: Is that a JavaScript or SQL error? If the latter I expect there is a problem with your SQL somewhere.